# How do I use pynput in Linux, or is pynput not working on Linux?

Tags: python, linux, input, pynput

I wrote a small game with python that runs in terminal, the input is working on windows but not on Linux I am using pynput which is (I think) supposed to work cross platform.

this is the code I use to get input:

```
from pynput import keyboard
def getInput():
    with keyboard.Events() as events:
        event = events.get(1.0)
        if '{}'.format(event) == "Press(key=Key.up)" and inputKey[0]==False:
            inputKey[0]=True
        elif'{}'.format(event) == "Press(key=Key.right)" and inputKey[1]==False:
            inputKey[1]=True
        elif '{}'.format(event) == "Press(key=Key.down)" and inputKey[2]==False:
            inputKey[2]=True
        elif '{}'.format(event) == "Press(key=Key.left)" and inputKey[3]==False:
            inputKey[3]=True
        elif '{}'.format(event) == "Press(key='r')" and inputKey[4]==False:
            inputKey[4]=True
        elif '{}'.format(event) == "Press(key='q')" and inputKey[5]==False:
            inputKey[5]=True
```

what I tried to test:

```
from pynput import keyboard
def getInput():
    with keyboard.Events() as events:
        event = events.get(1.0)
        print('{}'.format(event))
```

Comment: Your sample code runs just fine for me under Linux. Can you tell us more about how you're running it?

Comment: Im on Ubuntu im just running it with the command: 'python3 test.py' and im calling the method inside a while loop.

Comment: So how do you know its not working? Does your program print anything to let you know it is running?

Comment: The programm does run on windows and on linux, but it is suposed to do something when there a certain input, this works fine on windows but on linux it just outputs the entered key, if for example if a is pressed a if up is pressed something like [[A

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are running on Wayland (since Ubuntu uses it by default).

[`pynput` is meant to work on Xorg](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/limitations.html#linux) (it's `uinput` backend seems to be broken and never worked for me).

Try to switch to Xorg and let me know whether it worked.

Alternatively you can use [keyboard module](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard) which is quite similar and works on Wayland/Xorg/Windows/macOS.